# Convert all the string values to int from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

Sorry for this beginner question:

I'm getting this as response:

```
{id: "bitcoin", name: "Bitcoin", symbol: "BTC", rank: "1", price_usd: "15487.0"}
```

Now i would like to convert `rank: "1", price_usd: "15487.0"` to `rank: 1, price_usd: 15487.0`

The reason I need this i because my table sorts alphanumeric instead numeric.

How can I do this?

Comment: The native sorting order will still be in lexicographic order even if you converted the strings to numbers. Search for numeric sorting.

Comment: Issue is with sort function then. You need to customize if for numeric sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with,

```
var obj = {id: "bitcoin", name: "Bitcoin", symbol: "BTC", rank: "1", price_usd: "15487.0"};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((itm) => {
 if(!Number.isNaN(+obj[itm])) obj[itm] = +obj[itm];
});

console.log(obj);
```

A simple number conversion is playing the role here. If a non numerical string gets converted into a number by using the `+` operator, it will return a `NaN`. By using that we could achieve what you want.

If you want to use a reliable way of checking `NaN`, then go with the below approach,

```
var obj = {id: "bitcoin", name: "Bitcoin", symbol: "BTC", rank: "1", price_usd: "15487.0"};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((itm) => {
 let conv = +obj[itm];
 if(conv == conv) obj[itm] = +obj[itm];
});

console.log(obj);
```

This is a reliable approach. Because as per ECMA script, the reliable way to check whether a number is `NaN` is to check whether the number is equal to itself or not. If it is not equal, then that number is `NaN`.

Comment: still remains string for `"0"`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks man, I didn't really think of it. Just updated the answer.

Comment: @charlietfl `NaN` would also be a number. Thinking of a better solution. Give me a sec

Answer (score 1):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can be used to convert or filter values:

```js
j = '{"id":"bitcoin","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","rank":"1","price_usd":"15487.0"}'

o = JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => isNaN(+v) ? v : +v)

console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mysql as database you can make your column in table `rank` as int and price_usd as `decimal` then sort will work correctly.

if you want to convert your data client side. then you can do like this

```
for(var k in data) {
if(k == 'price_usd') {
 data[k] = parseFloat(data[k]);
  }
// for rank also
 }
```